# javascript change img onclick according to an img that was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

I'm trying to use the function onclick when pressing on an img.
I would like to change a big and main img ("mainPants") according to the small img that was pressed.
There is a problem with my code - every 'click' on the small img changes the main img to the last one (red pants).

here is my code:

```
<img  id="mainPants" src="images/bluePants.png">
<img class="img1" id="pBlack"  onclick="changeImage()" src="images/blackPants.png">
<img  class="img1" id="pPink" onclick="changeImage()" src="images/pinkPants.png">
<img class="img1" id="pRed" onclick="changeImage()" src="images/redPants.png">

        <script>
            function changeImage(){

                var blackPants = document.getElementById("pBlack");
                var pinkPants = document.getElementById("pPink");
                var redPants = document.getElementById("pRed");

                var newImg = document.getElementById('mainPants');

                    blackPants.addEventListener('onclick', function(){
                        newImg.src = "images/blackPantsBig.png";

                    }());

                    pinkPants.addEventListener('onclick', function(){
                        newImg.src = "images/pinkPantsBig.png";
                    }());

                    redPants.addEventListener('onclick', function(){
                        newImg.src = "images/redPantsBig.png";
                    }());


            };
        </script>
```

Comment: `onclick` is the property. With `addEventListener()` you have to use the name of the event which is `click` (without `on`) -> `.addEventListener('click', ...`

Comment: still not working...

Comment: `... onclick=changeImage(this) ...` + `function changeImage(img) { document.getElementById("mainPants").src = img.src; }`

Comment: but I want to change it to the big image by knowing "this" (this is the small img)
it's like ebay when you click on a small img you see it instead of the big img that was before

Comment: `img` would be the clicked image. You're free to do anything you want with it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You run all your callbacks on every click:

```
blackPants.addEventListener('onclick', function(){
    newImg.src = "images/blackPantsBig.png";
}()); // these "()" brackets run function right after it is created
```

You also bind all callbacks twice - the first time in HTML with `onclick="changeImage()"` attribute and the second time with an `addEventListener`. Try that:

```
<script>
  function changeImage(e) {
    var newImg = document.getElementById('mainPants');
    switch (e.target.id) {
      case 'pBlack':
        newImg.src = "images/blackPantsBig.png";
        break;
      case 'pPink':
        newImg.src = "images/pinkPantsBig.png";
        break;
      case 'pRed':
      default:
        newImg.src = "images/pinkPantsBig.png";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="img1" id="pBlack"  onclick="changeImage(this)" src="images/blackPants.png">
<img  class="img1" id="pPink" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="images/pinkPants.png">
<img class="img1" id="pRed" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="images/redPants.png">

    <script>
      function changeImage(img) {
        var newImg = document.getElementById('mainPants');
        switch (img.id) {
          case 'pBlack':
            newImg.src = "images/blackPantsBig.png";
            break;
          case 'pPink':
            newImg.src = "images/pinkPantsBig.png";
            break;
          case 'pRed':
          default:
            newImg.src = "images/redPantsBig.png";
        }
      }
    </script>
```